# I can't figure out how to pass parameters in the body of this SOAP API

Tags: xml, soap, postman, soapui

I am still relatively new SOAP APIs and I have been tasked with trying to figure out how to utilize WSAPI for Vertafore's AMS360 application. Here are some links to their documentation:

- [API Overview](https://link.vertafore.com/VERTAFORE/documentation/AMS360/content?apiSlug=AMS360:WSAPI:22f503&resourceSlug=R25236690)
- [Were to Download WSDL File](https://link.vertafore.com/VERTAFORE/documentation/AMS360/content?apiSlug=AMS360:WSAPI:22f503&resourceSlug=R74d8eb7f)
- [API Reference Guide](https://link.vertafore.com/VERTAFORE/documentation/AMS360/content?apiSlug=AMS360:WSAPI:22f503&resourceSlug=R659cd175)

I think that if I can just understand how to pass parameters correctly in the XML for one of the requests, then I can figure out the rest. For instance, how would I pass the parameters into the following XML:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v3="http://www.WSAPI.AMS360.com/v3.0">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <v3:WSAPISession>
         <v3:Ticket>?</v3:Ticket>
      </v3:WSAPISession>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v3:AgencyInfoGet/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

[Here is a link to that request's documentation,](https://link.vertafore.com/VERTAFORE/documentation/AMS360/content?apiSlug=AMS360:WSAPI:22f503&resourceSlug=R659cd175) where is shows that parameters that need to be passed... I just don't understand how because it doesn't provide a full example.

**Update 2/12/2024:**
I had to circle back to this because it turned into a black hole. I took a whole course on SOAP API I didn't want to waste anyone's time with my lack of knowledge. I feel like I can use everyone else's SOAP APIs, except Vertafore's now. I am not sure if the API documentation is bad or if I am still just terrible at SOAP. I finally got some sample code from Vertafore as well. I am returning a 404-File or directory not found error.... which is better than the nothing I was receiving before. I am now working with the login endpoint as you suggested in the answers. Can you see what I am getting wrong?

**The Sample Call From Vertafore:**

```
THIS CALL IS TO LOGIN

POST https://wsapi.ams360.com/v3/WSAPIService.svc HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://www.WSAPI.AMS360.com/v3.0/WSAPIServiceContract/Login"
Host: wsapi.ams360.com
Content-Length: 409
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <Login xmlns="http://www.WSAPI.AMS360.com/v3.0">
            <Request xmlns:a="http://www.WSAPI.AMS360.com/v3.0/DataContract" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:AgencyNo>REPLACE_ME</a:AgencyNo>
                <a:LoginId>REPLACE_ME</a:LoginId>
                <a:Password>REPLACE_ME</a:Password>
                <a:EmployeeCode/>
            </Request>
        </Login>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**In Postman I have the following:**

`Post https://wsapi.ams360.com/v3/WSAPIService.svc HTTP/1`

**Headers:**

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://www.WSAPI.AMS360.com/v3.0/WSAPIServiceContract/Login"
```

**Body:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Login xmlns="http://www.WSAPI.AMS360.com/v3.0">
        <Request xmls:a="http://www.WSAPI.AMS360.com/v3.0/DataContract" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:AgencyNo>REPLACE_ME</a:AgencyNo>
            <a:LoginId>REPLACE_ME</a:LoginId>
            <a:Password>REPLACE_ME</a:Password>
            <a:EmployeeCode/>
        </Request>
    </Login>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Important Note** - In the actual body in Postman I have replaced each "REPLACE_ME" with the correct values. This should still be testable without those values because my problem is simply accessing the endpoint in the first place, then I will worry about making sure the parameter values are correct.

Comment: None of the links work for me. Also, what have you tried so far? Where are you struggling? There is not enough information in your question to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to utilize the WSAPI you need to login to get a ticket.

This "ticket" then allows you to access the API and acts as your credential which you pass along with subsequent requests to authenticate.

Here's a link to the [login endpoint documentation](https://link.vertafore.com/VERTAFORE/documentation/AMS360/content?apiSlug=AMS360:WSAPI:22f503&resourceSlug=R659cd175).

You'll need to make a successful login request first, parse the response and use that token in your subsequent requests.

Comment: Okay, I had to circle back to this because it turned into a black hole. I took a whole course on SOAP API I didn't want to waste anyone's time with my lack of knowledge. I feel like I can use everyone else's SOAP APIs, except Vertafore's now.  I finally got some sample code from Vertafore as well (see update in description). I am returning a 404-File or directory not found error.... which is better than the nothing I was receiving before. I am now working with the login endpoint as you suggested (Which, thank you for that). Can you see what I am getting wrong (See post update)?